# Switching rows & columns in a matrix with O(1) complexity

Tags: c++

So for homework, one of the things I've been tasked with is swapping 2 rows or 2 columns with each other with a matrix that's built in a class type object, using those 3 parameters to define it:

```
size_t _R;// Number of rows.
size_t _C;// Number of columns.
std::vector<T> mat;// array of T type variables to represent the matrix.
```

For example if I had 3 rows and 3 columns and the int vector array of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, swapping rows 0 and 1 would make it look like 4,5,6,1,2,3,7,8,9.

So making the swap happen isn't the problem here, what I don't understand though is **how are you meant to make that happen with O(1) complexity?**

What I wanted to do is individually switch between every type in the row/column, but then that'd be O(n), right? Because it'd depend on the amount of items in each row/column.

EDIT:
Example code for what I tried:

```
void swap_rows(const size_t& r1, const size_t& r2) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < _C; i++)
    {
        T temp = mat[i + (r1 * _C)];
        mat[i + (r1 * _C)] = mat[i + (r2 * _C)];
        mat[i + (r2 * _C)] = temp;
    }
}
```

But I believe that's O(n) complexity, therefore a no-go :p

Comment: Please show us what you've tried

Comment: Gonna take a few minutes then since I've only considered it in theory so far(was no point making it if it wasn't the answer, right?:p)

Comment: Given the representation as a plain vector, I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: Well, you need to at least try and then we can correct your code and help you improve your code. If we just give you a code that you can hardly understand, then whats the point. On the other hand, if you try it yourself and we point out the mistakes , it will not only give you more practice but will also help you understand what all problems you will encounter and how you can solve them

Comment: If you have an additional vector that contains the start of each row, you only need to swap those entries. O(1) swap, O(1) lookup, but O(n) additional memory (if n is the number of rows). Note that this won't change the actual matrix, only the value lookup, which is usually good enough, unless you need to matrix in a special format (e.g. for LAPACK, BLAS, PETSc or other libraries).

Comment: @Zeta's suggestion is a good one but remember there is more to O notation than meets the eye. This allows O(1) swapping and still O(1) access but absolute access time is slightly slower due to the extra look up. Which is best depends if you are swapping often or rarely.

Comment: @Zeta That's actually pretty smart ye :p I suppose there isn't a way of doing this in O(1) complexity without leaving the matrix structure intact. You should probably post that as the answer then.
Do you mind though if I wait up with accepting it until I figure out whether I'm allowed to do it like this or not? :d

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Feel free to accept Component 10's answer, there's not really much to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to apply an *modifying* row and column to each of your dimensions, like:

```
std::vector<size_t>(_R) row_i;
std::vector<size_t>(_C) col_i;
```

These are then each initialised to e.g. `{0, 1, 2}` respectively. You then access your items by de-referencing through these collections:

```
T getItem( size_t row, size_t column )
{
    return mat[ ( row_i[row] * _C ) + col_i[col] ) ];
}
```

This will give you the item `T` at `row`, `col` but with the added de-reference through the modifying row and column.

Now, to swap two rows for example, you just need to say:

```
std::swap( row_i[0], row_i[1] );
```

and hey presto, the next time you access this, rows 0 & 1 will be switched over. It won't matter if you've a 3 x 3 matrix or 1000 x 1000, the modification time is always that of just swapping two ints in a vector.

Comment: Keep in mind that this gives another layer of indirection. Depending on the frequency of swaps, you'd rather want to swap. Either way, don't forget to run a profiler before you try to optimize your program.

Comment: If this is permitted, just add a transposed flag.

Comment: @MiloYip: Which helps if you need to transpose the matrix, but not if you want to swap two specific rows.

Answer (score -2):

A vector is random access with no indirection, so your problem is always O(_C) * O(2) = O(_C) for 2 rows in a vector.

If you want O(1) than represent the matrix as arrays of rows, so you can swap two row pointers. Swapping two cols then means, you got the same result O(_R).

Comment: That's still O(n), since `std::swap` on arrays uses `swap_range`. (It _would work_ on `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`).

Comment: you're right the code is wrong. row swapping would work on `T *mat[_R]; for(int i=0; /* ... */) {mat[i] = new T[_C]; } /* ... */ std::swap(mat[3], mat[4]);` for swapping 4th and 5th row

Comment: Nope, in case he has a two level of pointers, swapping two rows only implies changing the pointers to the rows.

Comment: ... and it would be a solution. Think about algorithms using the implementation of @Component 10. They'd always calculate the index for each element. My implementation only uses one indirection to access the complete row.